# Display the current value in bootstrap select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I want to filter some information, so when I click a button, the input field displays the current value.

For example:

When I select fruits and then click the filter button, I want the text of fruits to stay on the select option field.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<select class="form-control">
  <option>-Select-</option>
  <option>Fruits</option>
  <option>Vegetables</option>
  <option>Animal</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: And where is your input field?

Comment: @Tushar Sorry not input field, but select option field

Comment: You can use $("select").Val("Fruits"); but I want to know does page refreshes when you click on submit btn ?

Comment: @Akhilesh Ya. The page will refresh when i click on submit button

Comment: So which method are you using get or post ?

Comment: @Akhilesh I use get method

Comment: where does it submits the page i.e. it request on same page or any other page and are you using php ?

Comment: @Akhilesh on the same page. im using laravel

Comment: can you show that what are you returning from Laravel controller after submit this filter form

Comment: @Zaini return view('events.index')
            ->with('select', $select)

Comment: try $("select option:selected").text();

Answer (score 0):

try (edit:sorry, misunderstand your problem)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <select id='se' class="form-control">
    <option value="">-Select-</option>
      <option>Fruits</option>
      <option>Vegetables</option>
      <option>Animal</option>
    </select>

    
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$(function(){$('option:checked').removeClass('d-none').siblings().addClass('d-none')});">Filter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("select").val();
    });
});
```